# Objects Arrays, javascript. - JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

this is not my native language, and I'm new at StackOverflow. So I'm sorry if I wrote something wrong or violate some forum rule from start.
I just wanna know if I can simplify this, using classes, avoiding the id's from some tags, or auto-generate a JSON object from this form.

```
<div id="formulario1">
    <label class="elemento">#Manzanas<input type="checkbox" id="elem1"><input type="number" id="val1"></label>
    <label class="elemento">#Bananas<input type="checkbox" id="elem2"><input type="number" id="val2"></label>
    <label class="elemento">#Peras<input type="checkbox" id="elem3"><input type="number" id="val3"></label>
    <label class="elemento">#Naranjas<input type="checkbox" id="elem4"><input type="number" id="val4"></label>
</div>
<button id="enviar">enviar</button>
<script>
    const a = document.getElementById("formulario1");
    var arr = [
        elem1 = {
            check: document.getElementById("elem1").checked,
            value: document.getElementById("val1").value,
        },elem2 = {
            check: document.getElementById("elem2").checked,
            value: document.getElementById("val2").value,
        },elem3 = {
            check: document.getElementById("elem3").checked,
            value: document.getElementById("val3").value,
        },elem4 = {
            check: document.getElementById("elem4").checked,
            value: document.getElementById("val4").value,
        }
    ];

    const boton = document.getElementById("enviar");
    boton.addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log(arr[0]);
        console.log(arr[1]);
        console.log(arr[2]);
        console.log(arr[3]);
        var arr_json = (JSON.stringify(arr));
        console.log(arr_json);
    });
<script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you explain yourself about what is the output that you expect?

Comment: You are defining `arr` before the user has a chance to interact with your form. It should all be inside the `click` listener.

Comment: the output of the click handler will never change, because you build `arr` once, and the state of the checkboxes and inputs AT THAT TIME are stored in arr - if you put that `var arr=` code inside the click handler you should see a different result if you change the inputs before clicking the button

Comment: How is this a "php" question?

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate over all the available checkboxes in form element. See below example:

```
function loopForm(form) {
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
    if (form.elements[i].type == 'checkbox') {
        arr.push({ check: form.elements[i].checked, value: form.elements[i].value });
    }
}
var arr_json = (JSON.stringify(arr));
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr_json;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do to avoid quite so many `document.getElementById`s in there is use `document.querySelectorAll` instead, which would return an array of HTML nodes. That would return all matching nodes and you could iterate through those to get the values. In the HTML you shared, `document.querySelectorAll('#formulario1 input')` would get you all the inputs, but I would encourage you to use the `name` attributes on the HTML inputs so you have some idea what the values represent.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Also, as many astute commenters have already pointed out, you want to check the value of these DOM nodes **inside** the `boton.addEventListener` callback. As written, those values will never change.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow, best community in the world!

I understand that you are new to JS and it's exactly what i was when i started as a web developer. Your script can be refactored for sure by creating a function to initialized element rather than create every single element. You can simple using a for loop to do that. Please see my quick refactored code

```
<div id="formulario1">
  <label class="elemento">#Manzanas<input type="checkbox" id="elem1"><input type="number" id="val1"></label>
  <label class="elemento">#Bananas<input type="checkbox" id="elem2"><input type="number" id="val2"></label>
  <label class="elemento">#Peras<input type="checkbox" id="elem3"><input type="number" id="val3"></label>
  <label class="elemento">#Naranjas<input type="checkbox" id="elem4"><input type="number" id="val4"></label>
</div>
<button id="enviar">enviar</button>
<script>
  const a = document.getElementById("formulario1");

  //Old code
  // var arr = [
  // elem1 = {
  // check: document.getElementById("elem1").checked,
  // value: document.getElementById("val1").value,
  // },
  // elem2 = {
  // check: document.getElementById("elem2").checked,
  // value: document.getElementById("val2").value,
  // },
  // elem3 = {
  // check: document.getElementById("elem3").checked,
  // value: document.getElementById("val3").value,
  // },
  // elem4 = {
  // check: document.getElementById("elem4").checked,
  // value: document.getElementById("val4").value,
  // }
  // ];

  //=========================

  //refactored version

  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    arr.push(createElem(i + 1));
  }

  const boton = document.getElementById("enviar");

  //old code   
  // boton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // console.log(arr[0]);
  // console.log(arr[1]);
  // console.log(arr[2]);
  // console.log(arr[3]);
  // var arr_json = (JSON.stringify(arr));
  // console.log(arr_json);
  // });

  //refactored version


  boton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
      console.log(arr[i]);
    }
    var arr_json = (JSON.stringify(arr));
    console.log(arr_json);
  });

 // new function to create Element
  function createElem(index) {
    const elem = {
      check: document.getElementById(i).checked,
      value: document.getElementById(i).value,
    }
    return elem;
  }

</script>
```

or runable version at 
    https://jsfiddle.net/x40whk5d/2/

There are other things could be improved but i believe you can easily find it yourself when you have a deeper understanding later on. I've already commented out your code and add my new code to help you have a better view. Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I made a solution with JS Classes and withouth all the CSS class or Id, the resultant data is this:

```
{
  "input0":{"checkbox":true,"input":"23423"},
  "input1":{"checkbox":false,"input":""},
  "input2":{"checkbox":false,"input":""},
  "input3":{"checkbox":false,"input":""}
}
```

[Here you can see the solution in codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/get-form-data-in-oop-style-8x8f9)

Answer (score -1):

thanks all of you for you replies! I't worked. This is the output i was looking for. Thaks!

```
const contenedor = document.getElementById('contenedor');
        const elem = contenedor.querySelectorAll('.caja');
        const elem2 = contenedor.querySelectorAll('.cajas');
    document.getElementById('accion').addEventListener('click', function(){
        var i = 0; //variables
        let arr = [];
        for(i; i< elem.length; i++){
            arr.push({texto:elem[i].value, valor: elem2[i].value});
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
    });
```